# Real-Time Object Detection using Azure Kinect camera

Tags: azure, opencv, computer-vision, object-detection, azurekinect

I'm working on a project where I have to flag any foreign objects within a region of interest, other than two detector heads that are always present. My company ordered two Azure Kinect cameras to implement this and I was following this tutorial on real-time object detection using OpenCV on the pyimagesearch website to accomplish this. However, I have not been able to find any means of using OpenCV or real time object detection libraries with the Kinect camera. Kind of desperate to get some help with this so I would greatly appreciate any help regarding this!

Answer (score -1):

Though there wasn't an explicit mention of the support for OpenCV Python, their SDK definitely supports OpenCV C++.

Check this implementation: [OpenCV COmpatibility](https://github.com/microsoft/Azure-Kinect-Sensor-SDK/tree/develop/examples/opencv_compatibility)

Additionally Docs: [Azure Kinect Camera Docs](https://github.com/microsoft/Azure-Kinect-Sensor-SDK/tree/develop/docs)